# How to arrange image and text to appear side by side?

Tags: graphics

I want to place an image on my document and have it appear, say, on the right part of the page with text flowing on the left. How can I do that with LaTeX? Just like one would do with HTML and images “floating” to the right (or left).

(when searching I found some [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50551/how-to-arrange-image-and-text-side-by-side) questions which, however, were closed. I'm actually asking the question because I think it is a good question and should have a good answer on the site. Btw, assume I'm not using beamer nor anything fancy.)

Comment: Full example including minimal [Spacing around image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34113) for `wrapfig`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap text around a tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49300/wrap-text-around-a-tabular)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The `wrapfig` package is perhaps the best package to provide such functionality. The following is an example of how to use such package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
%------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.
%------------------------------------------
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
\caption{A wrapped figure going nicely inside the text.}\label{wrap-fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{sample}
\end{wrapfigure} 
%------------------------------------------
\lipsum[2-3]

Figure~\ref{wrap-fig:1} is a wrapped figure.
%------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Do you know a way to make `wrapfig` respect margins, like `graphicx` does? If I put the image less than its height from the page end, the image trespasses margins and even page dimensions, getting cut out, instead of going in the next page, so I have to adjust it manually.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski Not sure. Maybe you want to write a small example showing the undesired behaviour and post as a new question!

Comment: [Done!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291274/wrapfig-make-wrapped-image-respect-margins-and-page-ends)

Comment: How about the figure on the left?

Comment: How does your code work? There is a { besides \lipsum[2-3], but no closing bracket. And then there is a mysterious \par

Comment: Yep, there's something wrong here. `{` and `\par` can be safely removed ;).

Comment: I don't have LaTeX at hand to double-check. But remember others can edit/improve the answer if needed. :)

Comment: Note that replacing the `r` with an `R` after `\begin{wrapfigure}` causes the figure to float, which can help prevent the figure from protruding into the margins of the page.

Answer (score 10):

The `wrapfig` package is perhaps the package that provides functionality most like a html/css float.

There are 142 posts returned from a search of this site for wrapfig. Yiannis gives one in his comment above, another useful example is

[Wrap text around a tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49300/wrap-text-around-a-tabular)

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide a simple example of usage? (Just want to make this an excellent answer!)

Comment: I wasn't asking for me. I was asking for other people stumbling with this question.

Comment: I stumbled across this answer and it did not help me. We need an example.